# Is it possible to decide which view the UITouch gets bound to?

Tags: ios, uitouch, uiresponder, uievent

I have several UIViews that have somewhat complex shapes that I have drawn via each UIView's  drawRect: method. I have saved a reference to the path (via a CGPath property) and I am using that in my touches methods to detect whether or not the touch is actually within the path or shape (CGPathContainsPoint). Because of the shapes, there are areas of the view that are transparent (obviously anything that is not square/rectangular will have areas of transparency, assuming the view's backgroundColor property is set to clearColor or some such).

For situations (which occur often) where the view's end up on top or overlapping one another, I am testing in the touches methods (touchesBegan etc) to see if the touch is actually within the CGPath or shape. If the touch is not within the shape, I am forwarding the touch to the next view underneath to see if it in turn passes that requirement.

Sadly though (and much to my dismay), this does not behave the same as a touch actually being bound to the view. I have worked around this issue in every way except for one in particular. Each view is using a UIRotationGestureRecognizer. But if a touch originates in another view's transparent area, and that view forwards that touch to a view underneath it, the UIGestureRecognizer is never triggered.

I have looked at this from every angle I know how to. I have tried to think of some way of actually reassigning or binding the touch to the appropriate view, but I don't know if this is even possible. So long as the views are just forwarding the touch to another view, the touch will remain bound to the original view that received the touch first.

I wonder if you can do something this way by subclassing UIApplication or UIWindow and override the sendEvent:" method. I'm not sure exactly what control Apple might give you in this. I can't afford to do anything that might be accessing private API's. I really just need some way to reassign the touch so that the view thinks the touch belongs to it.

Any ideas?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by either subclassing UIView or subclassing UIGestureRecognizer.

## Subclassing UIView

By subclassing UIView (or any of its subclasses) and overriding

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

you can decide what points are considered to be inside your view. For points outside the path you simply return `NO`

## Subclassing UIGestureRecognizer

By subclassing UIGestureRecognizer (or any of its subclasses) and overriding

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

you can decide what touches the gesture recognizer should recognize. For all touches outside the path you should call (but not subclass)

```
- (void)ignoreTouch:(UITouch *)touch forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

on yourself.

---

## Point inside of path?

In either case you need to know if the points is inside of the path that you say you've stored.

If the paths are already stored as `UIBezierPath`s you can simply call

```
- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

On the bezier path. The point or the touch may need to be converted to the same view coordinates as the path by calling

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

or

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view
```

On your view.

If the path is stored as a CGPath you can create a UIBezierPath from it using

```
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:CGPath];
```

Comment: While this didn't completely answer the question, it put me on the right track. In looking into it a little more I found this blog posting that answered the question completely: http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=74 I accepted the answer though because it was a good effort and helped me figure out what I needed to know.

Comment: Is there something that I can clarify?

Comment: Because each view was "intercepting" the touches by overriding the touches methods (touchesBegan, moved, etc), - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event was never being called unless I touched outside of the view. But by following the link I provided above, I was able to override the hitTest: method of the underlying subview, and then use pointInside: to determine whether it was a valid touch. Also, while I'm sure you meant well with the "Point inside of path?" section, it was irrelevant as I stated that I was already doing this. Thanks again though